# Distribution of distinct object problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

So i was given this question. How many ways are there to place 10 distinct people within 3 distinct rooms with exactly 5 people in the first room and 2 people in the second room?

So i asked this question already but I did not get the answer I was looking for.

I was given the answer is ${10\choose 5}{5\choose 2}{3\choose 3}$ which can also be expressed as ${10\choose {5,2,3}}$.

That answer above was the method I thought as well but I asked my professor and she said

This is '
distribution
of distinct objects' problem, i.e. you enumerate people: 1, 2, ..., 10
and label rooms by A, B, C. Then put people in a row. If person #1 is
is room A, then you write A in the first position, if a person # 2 is
in room C, then you write C in the second position and so on. This
results in 10-letter sequence formed from A, B, C. Impose the given
restrictions and count such sequences.

The only way I knew was combinatorics but how would you do it with distribution of distinct objects?

Comment: It is the same idea. The number of ways is the number of $10$-letter "words" over the alphabet A, B, C where there are $5$ A's, $2$ B's, and $3$ C's.  We can choose where the A's go in $\binom{10}{5}$ ways, and so on.